# libef error during compilation

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I'm trying to install a program from source and keep getting an error related to libelf.
The program is a research-modified version of Dynamips from: 
https://github.com/Groundworkstech/dynamips-gdb-mod. It's a few years old and a whitepaper indicates the author had to update references to libelf too (see http://grid32.com/bb095447484a76e5c74d1…otkits.pdf) -- however I'm running the most current elfutils for ubuntu 16.04 TLS.

Full error message output:

```
#DYNAMIPS_ARCH=amd64 make

Linking dynamips
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `deflate_cleanup.6929':
(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_compress':
(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_compress':
(.text+0x26d): undefined reference to `deflate'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_compress':
(.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_decompress':
(.text+0x467): undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_decompress':
(.text+0x492): undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_decompress':
(.text+0x49f): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a(elf_compress.o): In function `__libelf_decompress':
(.text+0x4b3): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:228: recipe for target 'dynamips' failed
make: *** [dynamips] Error 1
```

Comment: The symbols it's complaining about are defined in libz. Just run configuration stage *(i.e. ./autogen.sh or ./configure, or whatever it's using)* with `-lz` added to LDFLAGS, e.g. `LDFLAGS="-lz" ./configure`, then try running make again. Ideally in this particular case you don't even have to clean anything, rerunning configuration should be enough.

Comment: @Hi-Angel is basically correct I think, however there's no `./configure` so you will likely need to edit `src/Makefile` by hand. In my case I was able to get it to build after modifying the `LIBS` line of the `ifeq ($(shell uname), Linux)` section to `LIBS=-L/usr/lib -L. -ldl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libelf.a $(PTHREAD_LIBS) -lz`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you so much. It worked for me.